# Error: Cannot Find Symbol from for loop

Tags: java

So my code is trying to find if a string is similar to another target string (target already defined). It makes a score based on how many letters are similar in both strings. However, in my for loop, I get a Cannot Find Symbol error for the m used in defining tChar, but it's been used to define iChar... I'm so confused. Is there a better way to do this?

```
public int score(String input){
    int score;
    char iChar, tChar;
    for (int m=0;m<input.length();++m)
        iChar = input.charAt(m);
        tChar = target.charAt(m);
        if (iChar == tChar)
            score = score + 1;
        else
            score = score;
    return score;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int m=0;m<input.length();++m) 
    iChar = input.charAt(m);  // Only this statement come under loop.
```

The scope of `m` is only with in first statement following the `for` loop, if you are not using `{}`. So, the following statement(s) there after doesn't come under for loop. Instead you need to do -

```
for (int m=0;m<input.length();++m)  // Now m is block scoped
{
        iChar = input.charAt(m);
        tChar = target.charAt(m);
        if (iChar == tChar)
            score = score + 1;
        else
            score = score;   // I don't see any use of else at all
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put bracers around your for loop. At the moment the for loop is just executing the **iChar** line over and over, then when it exits and gets to the **tChar** line, the variable **m** is out of scope and so cannot be found.

The repaired code is below.

```
public int score(String input) {
    int score = 0; //i know java instantiates variables for you, but if you do it explicitly, it serves to document your code.
    char iChar, tChar;
    for (int m = 0; m < input.length(); m++) {
        iChar = input.charAt(m);
        tChar = target.charAt(m);
        if (iChar == tChar) score++; //abbreviated and else clause removed, as it was doing nothing.
    }
    return score;
}
```